# How to check if item is related to certain other item in many to many relationship?

Tags: symfony

I have `document entity` with one to many relation to `documentstags entity`.

How may I check whether certain document is related to documentstags with certain "tag" column value?

Documents entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Documentstags", mappedBy="documentid")
*/
protected $tags;
```

Documentstags entity:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=220)
     */
    protected $tag;
```

How may I check whether document A is related to Documentstags item which tag value e.g. B?

Currently I have implemented the following code as function of `Documents entity` but it does not seems to be effecient:

```
$tags = $this->getTags();
        $is_zatwierdzony = false;
        foreach($tags as $tag)
        {
            if($tag.tag == $this->avaliabletags['zatwierdzony']['name']) $is_zatwierdzony = true
        }
```

Comment: Is the relationship reversed in Documentstags? If so, i think you should need to perform the check in your controller by getting all the Documentstags belonging to a specific Document and having the tag you are looking for. If it retrieves results, it means your document contains those tags. Another option would be to create a method in your Documents entity and iterate all your DocumentsTags, but i think it won't be as performant as the another option i mentioned.

Comment: Yes the relationship is reversed. How may I "get all the Documentstags belonging to a specific Document and having the tag you are looking for". Should I create custom function to to this or is there easier way?

Comment: Are you going to perform this from your controller? If so, you can use entities repositories functions to get what you need. Check here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) how it uses "findBy" with an array of parameters.

Comment: I will be doing it rather from function in documents entity. I may use `$tags = $this->getTags();` and illiterate threw each tag but I don't know if this will be effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use Criteria class:

for example:

```
...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
...

public function getMatchingTags() 
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
                ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("tag", $this->avaliabletags['zatwierdzony']['name']));

    $tags = $this->getTags()->matching($criteria);

    #do something with matching tags
}
```

---

Doctrine2 documentation: [Filtering Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)